# Linear Search in Linked List [Language: C++ Compiler: Dev-Cpp 4.9.9.2]

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem and can't seem to find the solution..

```
int linearSearch(nodeptr list,char search){
    int pos =0;
    if(list==NULL)
        return -1;
    while(list->info!=search && list!=NULL){
        pos++;
        list=list->next;
    }
    if(list==NULL)
        return -1;
    else
        return pos;
}
```

I always get a runtime error.. :(

Comment: What kind of error? And at a guess: `while(list->info!=search && list!=NULL)` should be the other way round. You dereference `list` before checking if it is `NULL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while(list->info!=search && list!=NULL)
```

should be:

```
while(list!=NULL && list->info!=search)
```

This is called as **[Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).**
When you use `&&` the first expression is guaranteed to be executed before the second **for inbuilt primitive types**<sup>[#1]</sup>.

In your case the dereferencing happens before the `NULL`check, So when `list == NULL`, You will end up derefrencing the `NULL`and causing an **Undefined Behavior** and a crash.

In the sugeested solution:
if `list == NULL` then the second condition will not be evaluated.

---

Reference:
<sup>[#1]</sup>**C++03 Standard 1.9.18:**

> In the evaluation of the following expressions
>
> ```
> a && b
> a || b
> a ? b : c
> a , b
> ```
>
> using the built-in meaning of the operators in these expressions, there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first expression (12).

Answer (score 2):

you are not checking for the validity of `list` here:

```
while(list->info!=search && list!=NULL)
```

try checking `list!=NULL` before `list->info`.

Also, don use the name `list`, it is the name of a standard library container.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` conditions are evaluated in the order they are specified, so in you case when `list` becomes `NULL` in the loop during the next iteration  you are first trying to do `list->info != search` which results in access violation. You need to reverse the condition to `list != NULL && list->info != search`.